# How to decode Common Industrial Protocol (CIP) packets using python?

Tags: python, wireshark, scapy, plc

I tried to decode this highlighted segment however i ran into some issues.
[image: Wireshark packet capturing CIP]

I used this code in order to decipher the content

```
hexed ="01000c0000000040000040400000803f0000003f2af0ce4004040000404000008040cdcc4c3ecdcccc3d305b1a3e2903fa42240000484400006144000048430000c8424ddc4143200000484400006144000048430000c84218380b440000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000b010001deddf7420b0100016666e6400201000102000000000000000000000000305b1a3e4ddc414318380b4400010000000101000100010002000300121204000200010000050006000600ffffffff00000000deddf742"
ether_pkt = Ether(binascii.unhexlify(hexed))
ether_pkt.show()
```

And the result i got is:

[image: Output of code]

How do i further decipher this content?

```
'\x80?\x00\x00\x00?*\xf0\xce@\x04\x04\x00\x00@@\x00\x00\x80@\xcd\xccL>\xcd\xcc\xcc=0[\x1a>)\x03\xfaB$\x00\x00HD\x00\x00aD\x00\x00HC\x00\x00\xc8BM\xdcAC \x00\x00HD\x00\x00aD\x00\x00HC\x00\x00\xc8B\x188\x0bD\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x01\x00\x01\xde\xdd\xf7B\x0b\x01\x00\x01ff\xe6@\x02\x01\x00\x01\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x000[\x1a>M\xdcAC\x188\x0bD\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x03\x00\x12\x12\x04\x00\x02\x00\x01\x00\x00\x05\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\xde\xdd\xf7B'
```

I've tried to .decode() and hex() in order to turn them into string however the output is not human readable

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [pycomm3](https://docs.pycomm3.dev/en/latest/index.html). Especially its [CIP reference](https://docs.pycomm3.dev/en/latest/cip_reference.html).

According to the reference, `0x4c` is the "read_tag" custom service for Rockwell devices, whatever that means.

The data you highlighted is listed as "command specific data". That suggests that it is not defined in the CIP, but is custom to the device that sent it. If it had been part of the CIP, wireshark could probably have decoded it further. So you will have to find and read documentation for the device in question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic, you need to download the specs and write a parser to decode it. As you can see in your wireshark screenshot, the protocol isn't string/ascii.

Comment: So, how do i know which direction to go in terms of which specs to download and which parser to use in order to decode?